# Pocket instruments?

Tags: instruments

I’ve heard of the guitarlele, but they are about 1/4 the size of a normal guitar.  I’m looking for some kind of guitar or other real instrument that would fit in a large pocket (no larger than 10 inches (25 cm) long.  It doesn’t have to be an instrument that is taken seriously by the music community, but needs to be viable in its musical ability.  Any ideas?

Comment: It isn't clear what your goal really is; if you want something guitar-ish you might have to settle for a [custom ukulele](https://ukulelemagazine.com/stories/news/video-the-worlds-smallest-playable-ukuleles). If you just want something small and playable, what about a harmonica?

Comment: I think there are also some miniature electronic instruments. But as ex nihilo said, it would be easier to answer if we had more details. In what kind of situation do you want to use the instrument?

Comment: Maybe some kind of recorder. A Tape Recorder perhaps!! Hahahahah (groan…)

Comment: What about your voice? You don't even need a pocket for it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's essentially a list question asking for all instruments under 10 inches. I recommend editing to narrow the field—are you looking specifically for string instruments? wind? does it need to be easy to learn? hard to break?

Comment: (Meanwhile, @user1079505, I've given my brother the Korg Monotron Duo and Delay for the last two Christmases. It seems like a pretty convenient way to allow a lot of creative outlet in a roughly pocket-size package.)

Comment: (And I can't resist continuing to offer suggestions: If you're looking specifically for an acoustic string instrument, there *is* one that is literally named for being "pocket-sized": the *[pochette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochette_(musical_instrument))* was mainly used by baroque dance instructors, being quiet enough to talk over. There are [recreations made today](https://www.etsy.com/listing/210066169/a-pochette-or-pocket-fiddle) (probably better ones than that, too).

Answer (score 1):

- Harmonica
- Slide whistle
- Sopranino recorder (~20cm: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sopranino_recorder))
- Various high-pitches whistles, flutes, recorders, and pipes
- Mbira ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbira)) might work depending on the pocket's width and depth.
- Jew's harp
- Spoons
- Kazoo

Comment: I feel like harmonica has to be the best answer. It can play chords and single notes, and chromatic ones are quite serious. Same with the mbira, now that I think about it.

Comment: I think the kazoo is the perfect device to justify occassional screaming and off-key singing.

Comment: Spoons?........